Get the BuildContext from within a callback function at the place it is called
I have made a Widget (MyComplexWidget) consisting of 2 other widgets A and B.
On construction of MyComplexWidget, I pass it a callback function for one of its children widget's (A, B) onTap/onPressed property.
The problem is that this callback requires the BuildContext of its current parent (e.g. Widget A or B) because, let's say, internally, it does a navigation:
Navigator.pushNamed(context, "newroute");
Ideally, I would like to have this:
MyComplexWidget(
  // this cb is eventually passed on
  // Widget A's and B's constructors.
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "newroute");
  }
);

with context being the BuildContext of the child widget (Widget A or B) which is assigned this onTap callback (inside MyComplexWidget) AND not the current BuildContext where the closure callback was created (IF ANY at all!).
BTW, Navigator.pushNamed() is just an example, there could be other things inside the callback which require the context. I am not asking for a solution on how to navigate without context etc.
How is this possible?

You have context in scope when you're "closing" that callback.  You do need to add tests to make sure the context is still mounted.

In getx if you want context you can use Get.context

I can't think of a situation where MyComplexWidget's context isn't good enough. Why would you exactly need A's context? I suppose if you really want to you could wrap A in a Builder and use the builder's context

By the way, if A is your own custom widget then you could also just define onTap as a function that takes the context as argument and call it with its own context

@Ivo, good idea! I am now creating the callback as void myOnTap(BuildContext context){ ... } and then in each A,B (which are standard widgets) etc. I do onTap : (){ myOnTap(context); },. It's a bit awkward but with this I will move a lot of logic from the build(BuildContext context) method to a run-once initialiser.

You can use a global key to find context of certain widget.
However this only work in callback, the context cannot be used directly in build such as padding: MediaQuery.paddingOf(navKey.currentContext!);
class NavWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavWidget({super.key, required this.navKey});
  final GlobalKey navKey;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if (navKey.currentContext == null) return;
        Navigator.pushNamed(navKey.currentContext!, '/next');
      },
      child: const Text('Next'),
    );
  }
}


@Ivo's comment, in my question, provided me with a solution in which:

the user-provided callback takes a context parameter, e.g. void myOnTap(BuildContext context){ ... }

You do not pass directly this callback to each basic Widget's onTap property but you provide it like this: onTap: (){ myOnTap(context); } (and context is now available as we are inside a build() method).


For example,
// untested pseudocode
class MyComplexWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function(BuildContext)? onTapForA;
  final void Function(BuildContext)? onTapForB;

  const MyComplexWidget({super.key, this.onTapForA, this.onTapForB});

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      InkWell( // basic widget A
        ...
        onTap: () {
          onTapForA!(context);
        },
      ),
      InkWell( // basic widget B
        ...
        onTap: () {
          onTapForB!(context);
        },
      )
    ]);
  } // build
}

Thank you for your help
